# R extract multiple numbers from strings inside brackets Regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string

```
cutoff     `KM Median rwToT (95% CI)` `Restricted mean rwToT @ 24 months (95% CI)`
  <chr>      <chr>                      <chr>                                       
1 2017-01-01 2.1 (1.4 - 4.9)            7.2 (3.9 - 10.2) [LogNorm]                  
2 2017-04-01 3.5 (2.1 - 4.7)            8.9 (6.6 - 10.8) [LogNorm]                  
3 2017-07-01 3.7 (2.8 - 4.2)            7.2 (6.2 - 8.4) [Weibull]
```

I have this table. I am trying to extract and separate the numbers from `KM Median rwToT (95% CI)` and `Restricted mean rwToT @ 24 months (95% CI)` columns. I know I am supposed to use the regular expression but I am not sure how to extract the numbers inside the brackets.

Here is the sample data

```
structure(list(cutoff = c("2017-01-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-07-01"), 
        `KM Median rwToT (95% CI)` = c("2.1 (1.4 - 4.9)", "3.5 (2.1 - 4.7)", "3.7 (2.8 - 4.2)"), `Restricted mean rwToT @ 24 months (95% CI)` = c("7.2 (3.9 - 10.2) [LogNorm]", 
            "8.9 (6.6 - 10.8) [LogNorm]", "7.2 (6.2 - 8.4) [Weibull]")), row.names = c(NA, 
            -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `separate` as follows. First we define Separate to be like separate except the sep pattern is fixed to what we need and convert is fixed to be TRUE.

Note that `[^[:alnum:].]+` refers to using strings of characters that are not alphabetic, numeric or dot as separators. Also note that because the fields end in a delimiter (parenthesis or square bracket) that `separate` will assume that there is an extra field at the end so use NA to skip it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Separate <- function(...) separate(..., sep = "[^[:alnum:].]+", convert = TRUE)

DF %>%
  setNames(c("cutoff", "KM", "Rest")) %>%
  Separate(KM, into = c("KM", "KM_lo", "KM_hi", NA)) %>%
  Separate(Rest, into = c("Rest", "Rest_lo", "Rest_hi", "model", NA))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  cutoff        KM KM_lo KM_hi  Rest Rest_lo Rest_hi model  
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1 2017-01-01   2.1   1.4   4.9   7.2     3.9    10.2 LogNorm
2 2017-04-01   3.5   2.1   4.7   8.9     6.6    10.8 LogNorm
3 2017-07-01   3.7   2.8   4.2   7.2     6.2     8.4 Weibull
```